# Where do I find the stack trace when debugging Flutter in Intellij Idea Community?

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea

I am using the Intellij Idea Community edition editor to write a Flutter app. When I get an exception or hit a breakpoint I can't find the place in the IDE where I can view the stacktrace. There must be a window for it somewhere.
If I hit a breakpoint I can click the 'Debug' tab and I have a 'Frames' and a 'Variables' tab, I have the icons to step over, step into etc. but can't see where to view the stacktrace.

Where do I go to to get a stacktrace ?

Flutter Channel stable, 3.0.0
Flutter Doctor says everything is OK.
Intellij Idea is version 2021.3.3 Build #IC-213.7172.25

Thank you

Comment: It should be in the `Frames` pane. Do you have the correct drop down selected in Frames?

Comment: I have a dropdown in the Frames pane but it only contains one entry - 'Main'. The Frames window lists Flutter framework calls - I don't see any of my own code in there.  Do I need to tell Intellij not to list framework calls ?

Comment: There are going to be a *lot* of framework calls; what were you expecting instead? Where are you setting your breakpoints? In a Bloc, or a build method or initState?

Comment: My breakpoints could be in one of my plain Dart classes or in the build method of classes derived from StatefulWidget. I have tried adding my Flutter install directory to the 'Do not step into classes' list but the framework calls still appear in the list. I was expecting/hoping to see a call stack containing methods just from my own code.

Comment: Try running flutter run -v for verbose details while you run the project.

Comment: @Kaushik Chandru, Thanks for helping, the -v option just gives me lots of info in the Terminal window. Does that give me a stacktrace anywhere ?

Comment: Can you update the question with a screenshot showing a typical breakpoint and the frames pane. If you are setting a breakpoint in `build`, your code will always be the last thing called, as build is always called from the framework. I'm wondering why you'd expect to see any of your other methods further up the stacktrace.

Comment: I tried to add a screenshot but I don't have enough reputation points. If I put a breakpoint in a Dart class that is part of my business logic it might be called from a number of places, isn't it normal to want to see who called the currently executing line of code ?

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter logs` and connect your device and run it. It should show all logs. Also a quick tip. If you run `flutter -h` it will display all available commands. Then if you run `flutter run -h` this will show all commands available for flutter run. You should also see info, verbose, logs etc.

Comment: But what about a stacktrace when a breakpoint is hit ?

Comment: Please have a look at this link. https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/debugger#the-call-stack-and-variable-areas